# Eloquent laravel, clone entity

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to clone an entity and the OneTomany relation too. For some reason, the $entity->hasManyRelation() is not a function. :/

Here's my code.:

```
$clonedWorksheet = Worksheet::where('id', $id)->get()->load('records');

$worksheet = new Worksheet;

$worksheet->employee_id = $request->employee;
$worksheet->workday = $request->workday;

$worksheet->save();

foreach ($clonedWorksheet->records() as $clonedRecord) {
  $record = new Record;

  $record->from = $clonedRecord->from;
  $record->to = $clonedRecord->to;
  $record->estimated = $clonedRecord->estimated;
  $record->place_id = $clonedRecord->place_id;
  $record->worksheet_id = $worksheet->id;
  $record->vehicle_id = $clonedRecord->vehicle_id;
  $record->tool_id = $clonedRecord->tool_id;
  $record->job_id = $clonedRecord->job_id;
  $record->comment = $clonedRecord->comment;

  $worksheet->records()->save($record);
}
```

Any other idea, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `()` from records in your foreach, so it will access the actual records instead of the function.

Comment: in addition to what @aynber said you could also do just $record = $clonedRecord; $worksheet->records()->save($record); or even use the clone magic method

Comment: Ah, I found it. I used get() instead of first() and get gives back a collection. Thank you guys, tho. :)

Comment: you need first put `clonedWorksheet` on foreach next put relation

Comment: For this functionality you might also want to look at the `->replicate()` method, as it would save you quite some lines. As for the origininal question, I believe it has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
foreach ($clonedWorksheet->records() as $clonedRecord) {
```

The records() is the method in the model that does the database query.  The return is an eloquent relationship object.  You want:

```
foreach($clonedWorksheet->records as $clonedRecord) {
```

Or

```
foreach ($clonedWorksheet->records()->get() as $clonedRecord) {
```

Models have a [replicate function](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate), which would cut the body of your loop down quite a bit to just:

```
$record = $cloneRecord->replicate();
$record->worksheet_id = $worksheet->id;
$record->save();
```